# Migrating to microservices, how can one refactor the front end so that it can be notified of failures?

Tags: frontend, microservices, backend, rollback

In a monolithic architecture, the front end usually makes one rest call to backend and backend does everything in one shot and returns a status code (`2xx, 4xx, 5xx`). The front end uses this status code to alter the display of information to the user.

In a microservices architecture, the front end will still make one call to backend, but this time, the backend which is broken into microservices may return a 2xx from its front end facing microservice (let's call this the `SUCCESS-SERVICE`) but some other service may fail (`FAILED-SERVICE`), which would need to result into a rollback.

Assuming that the microservices at backend are listening for events and the SUCCESS-SERVICE eventually rolls back its transaction (deletes the record).

How should one design the front end to capture the failure AFTER it got success from the first service already?

One pattern I can think of is right after getting a 2xx from the service, poll for the status of the newly created resource (`GET /resource/:id`) and look for a defined set of status messages that can indicate if the entire workflow succeeded or failed. Given the backend service would have rolled back the transaction, the GET call will eventually return a 4xx because the `id` would no longer be valid.

Is there another or better way to design the front end?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this approach would work, because there are not so many options to surface eventual consistency on the front-end level.

One idea that complements this approach would be to create a dedicated microservice that stores the state of the operations, in order to have a single point of polling in your backend (otherwise, depending on the workflow, you may need to poll in different microservices). This brings more consistency into the architecture at the cost of having a single point of failure.

It may also be useful to check out the way transactions can be done in microservices (interesting article [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/01/patterns-for-distributed-transactions-within-a-microservices-architecture#possible_solutions))

Comment: Thanks for the response and sharing the link on 2PC and Saga. I think there are many techniques on how to handle backend for rollbacks and commits, but not many on how to handle front end while backend is still going through its set of changes in multiple microservices. The option you present is definitely viable, but wondering if there is any fixed set of patterns app designers follow.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing is synchronous, the entrypoint service must aggregate responses from the other services and return the appropriate status code.

If the processing is asynchronous (typically when messaging is involved), then you should use the task pattern. The frontend invokes the entrypoint service to register a task, then it periodically polls the entrypoint service to get the status of the task. A task has at least three statuses : "in_progress", "ok", "error". This pattern is recommanded when the process is asynchronous, bu also when the processing time may take a long time (human approval, ...).